# Multiplication of the matrix exponential with a given vector in python

Tags: python, scipy

I am interested in compute the matrix exponential of a given sparse matrix `H` and then multiply it with a given vector `v`. Since the size of the matrix `H` becomes to be of order of 90.000, then compute explicitly it and then multiply by `v` becomes difficult (it spend a lot of time). The point is that I want to compute the time-evolution of the state `v`, where `H` is the Hamiltonian, for a given time:

```
U = exp(-i*H*t)
```

where `i` is the imaginary unit and `t` is the time. Then I want to multiply this matrix `U` by the vector `v` in order to obtain the evolution of this state `v`

On the other hand, I have found the following library in python:

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.expm_multiply
```

so:

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.expm_multiply(-(1j)*t*H,v)
```

which comes from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.expm_multiply.html. With this I can compute very efficiently only for small time. For a high time `t` it spends a lot of time, I don't know why...

Any idea why it happens? How can be solved?

My goal is make a table with several points of time and its respective evolved states

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The docs for that function reference a couple of scientific computing papers.  It may also help to read the code in `scipy/sparse/linalg/_expm_multiply.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first diagonalize H, and then represent v in that basis (the energy basis of quantum mechanics). Expressing v in this form will make it easy for you to compute subsequent time evolution.

Let e_i be the eigenvectors of H. Since H is a Hamiltonian it is Hermitian, and thus any vector v, has a complete and unique description as a linear superposition in the energy basis:

```
v = SUM(v_i * e_i)
```

with v_i unique constants. Then you can compute the time evolved state for any t as:

```
v(t) = SUM(exp(-i*t*lambda_i) * v_i *e _i)
```

where lambda_i is the eigenvalue H * e_i = lambda_i * e_i. Since this is just a bunch of scalar multiplications and a sum, it is quite efficient to compute.

The main slow down will be diagonalizing H, which algorithmically is of order O(N^3) (for an N x N matrix).

For small t, exp(-itH) is approximately 1 - itH (you can see this from a Taylor expansion), so of course this will be fast.

The above is, I am afraid, pretty much as fast as it's going to get (unless the system has some additional special properties). Simulation of quantum mechanics has some very real difficulties, and is what quantum computers are for ;P.

Comment: Ok thanks, but since the Hamiltonian matrix H has a dimension of order 90.000, it's impossible obtain all the eigenvectors of the system, (only the ground state and excited states), so that is not possible express the state v in terms of the basis of the system.

Comment: @Joe - then perhaps you should do some sort of slow-field approximation. Compute only the first few eigenvectors / eigenvalues and use those to get an approximate time evolution. This could be acceptable if you are only interested in the 'slow' parts of the dynamics and the high frequency modes can indeed be neglected. If you need the full solution, then unfortunately maths and computational realities are going to impose some rather tough limits.

Comment: @Joe - perhaps also look into the renormalization group and the process of systematically integrating out high energy modes in your specific problem domain to generate a valid low energy Hamiltonian that can be solved. There may be packages and / or papers that will help you get at the dynamics in an approximate but computationally feasible manner. However, we are already outside of the scope of stackoverflow - this is better suited for the physics board ;P.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36922/accurate-way-to-calculate-matrix-powers-and-matrix-exponential-for-sparse-positi